# Rubyのバイナリを作成したソフトにバンドルして配布しても良いでしょうか

Tags: ruby, ライセンス

Rubyを使ったアプリケーションを配布したいと考えています。
その際に、Rubyのバイナリも同梱した状態で配布しても問題ないでしょうか。

作成するソフトは商用製品またはGPL、LGPLをいずれかを考えています。

Comment: こちらの質問をきっかけに、「[ソフトウェアライセンスに関する質問をどう考えるか](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1541/30)」をメタに投稿しました。ご意見ある方はぜひお寄せください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ruby`自体を改造するという話ではなく、あくまで実行時に`Ruby`に渡して利用するソースコードの話と仮定します。そうした場合にアプリケーションのソースコードだけを別途独自のライセンスで配布することは問題ありません。(配布したいアプリケーションのソースコード内で`Ruby`のソースコードを含めている場合などは話は変わります。)

ですので、配布の際にはアプリケーションソースコードと`Ruby`のバイナリをそれぞれ別のライセンスで配布されれば良いのではないでしょうか。

ちなみに`Ruby`は`Ruby License`で管理されています。
`Ruby`公式サイトにある[license.txt](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/about/license.txt)を見ると、`2-clause BSDL`としてバイナリの配布が可能とあります。(あるいは前文より下に書かれている独自条項に従うことでも配布可能だそうです。いわゆるデュアルライセンスですかね。)

`2-clause BSDL`は`BSDL`の宣伝条項が排除された`修正BSDL`から、さらに"書面上の許可なく開発者の名称を派生物の推奨や販売促進に使用しないという項目を削除"(cf. [BSDライセンス - Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9))したライセンスです。

---

法的な話はこうしたサイトの範疇外ですので、実際には弁護士などに相談されることをお勧めします。この回答はあくまで個人的な見解であり、係る問題に対しての一切の責任は負いかねます。

Answer (score 4):

Ruby 本体の再配布の話であれば、バージョンによって二種類あります。

Ruby 1.9.2 以前のものは [GPLv2 + Ruby's](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_2/COPYING) のデュアルライセンス(GPLv3 非互換なので注意が必要のようです)、現在のものは [BSDL + Ruby's](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/COPYING) のデュアルライセンスです。

また、どちらにも、

> 4. You may modify and include the part of the software into any other
>      software (possibly commercial).  But some files in the distribution
>      are not written by the author, so that they are not under these terms.
>
>    For the list of those files and their copying conditions, see the
>      file LEGAL.

とありますので [LEGAL](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/LEGAL) を読んで、それぞれに従う必要があると思います。

ご参考までに、Ruby'sライセンスについては、[ここ](http://pub.cozmixng.org/~the-rwiki/rw-cgi.rb?cmd=view;name=Ruby%A4%CE%A5%E9%A5%A4%A5%BB%A5%F3%A5%B9)らへんなどを、 GPLv2 については[ここ(en.wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Version_2)らへんを、 BSDL については[ここ(en.wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#2-clause_license_.28.22Simplified_BSD_License.22_or_.22FreeBSD_License.22.29)などをどうぞ。

*(wikipediaも含め、出来る/出来ないの軽めの判断をするための情報なので、実際に再配布を行うことになったら専門家にご相談ください)*

Answer (score 2):

Rubyに対するライセンスは 「[2条項BSDライセンス (BSDL)](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/BSDL)」 と 「[Rubyのライセンス](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/COPYING)（[日本語訳](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/COPYING.ja)）」のデュアルライセンシングです。[Rubyのライセンス](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/COPYING.ja)は、MIT ライセンスのように緩やかなライセンスで、いくつかの制限を守れば好き勝手できるものと考えてよいです。（Ruby は、ソースコードで配布されるものです。実行ファイルを別のサイトから入手しそれを配布したい場合([例](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/blob/master/LICENSE.txt))は、その配布元のライセンスも確認してください。その実行ファイルには、別のライセンスを付加するライブラリが組み込まれている可能性があります。）

いくつかの制限により、「ruby を改変したならバイナリを ruby 以外の名前にする」などとしなければなりませんが、ほとんどの場合、Ruby の実行環境を使用したことおよび、[ruby-lang.org](https://www.ruby-lang.org/ja/)へのリンクをドキュメントに明示することでよいでしょう。Rubyのライセンスは短く簡潔なのでご自身で確かめられてください。

また、Ruby そのものについて問題がなかったとしても、使用した Ruby のライブラリ (各種 gem になると思います)には、それぞれの作者によるライセンスがありますので、そちらの確認漏れがないよう、注意してください。

※ バージョン 1.9.2 以前の Ruby は、 [GPLv2 との二重ライセンス](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_2/COPYING)になっていますので、注意してください。バージョンの 1.9.3 から BSDL との二重ライセンスで配布されています。

※ Ruby の一部のソースコードを改変・流用するときには、 [LEGAL](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/LEGAL) に注意してライセンスを考える必要があります。

参考: [Ruby'sライセンスの、BSDLとのデュアルライセンスへの変更](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-dev/42166)